# Strange behaviour of rstrip function in python with letter "l"

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, strip

I have a program in Python 2.7 which process some strings. If some strings ends in letter "l" (not "L", just "l"), rstrip deletes this "l" when it should not.
Example code:

```
file=u'isabel.algo'#final "l"
str="/"+file+"/"+file.rstrip(".algo")+".py"
print str
file=u'isabeL.algo'#final "L"
str="/"+file+"/"+file.rstrip(".algo")+".py"
print str
file='isabel.algo'#non unicode
str="/"+file+"/"+file.rstrip(".algo")+".py"
print str
```

Which results in:

```
/isabel.algo/isabe.py
/isabeL.algo/isabeL.py
/isabel.algo/isabe.py
```

As it can be seen, when "file" ends in "L" it has no problem. But when it ends in "l", the final string is wrong (it should be "isabel.py")

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should refer to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) of `rstrip`!

`rstrip` takes a list of characters that you want to strip off the end of your string. So `file.rstrip(".algo")` will strip all '.', 'a', 'l', 'g', and 'o' characters at the right end of your string.

A potential fix for this problem would be to `split` your string using '.' as the delimiter:

```
str="/"+file+"/"+file.split(".")[0]+".py"
```

Or as suggested chromano in the comments you can use the `replace` method:

```
str="/"+file+"/"+file.replace(".algo",".py")
```

Comment: Usage of .replace is then recommended.

Comment: Note that `haystack.replace('needle', 'foo')` will replace the needle at any point of the haystack, not only at the end. With a regular expression you can express this condition.

Comment: @PauloScardine I believe `.replace` should be suitable for replacing the file extension, but your point is certainly worth keeping in mind!